# input source menu icon missing and ibus language switching not working 15.04

Tags: unity, 15.04, keyboard-layout, language-support, ibus

I have installed `ibus-m17n` packages and added `ibus-daemon` in start up applications. Then I enabled `Show current input source in the menu bar` in `System settings > Text Entry`. I have noticed `Tamil(phonetic(m17n))(IBus)` is grayed. `Super + Space` is also not switching the language. Introduction of `fcitx` input method plays any role in this. IF so how can I adopt that method with indic languages(Tamil)?

[image]

Comment: tamil99 keyboard installed on 15.04 works fine for me. I followed the same thing that you mentioned here. Initially it didn't show up the new keyboards installed. Once I have restarted the machine, I see them available for selection. super+space is also working now to switch between the layouts.

Answer (score 1):

- Remove the ibus-deamon item in *Startup Applications*.
- Open *Language Support*, and select IBus as the "Keyboard input method system".
- Log out and log in again.

Now the input source indicator should be visible in the menu bar, and the m17n options available in *Text Entry*.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution didn't work ! Actually I have tried what you suggested for the first time, it didn't work then only I had my ibus-daemon